# Help in understanding a proof about infinite double summations

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, proof-explanation, double-sequence

[image: Exercise 2.8.5 a)]

[image: Solution]

This is a problem from the book Understanding Analysis. I am struggling understanding to things. First I do not see how the order limit theorem is used, and second how they go from strictly less to less or equal. Can anybody give me a explanation for these two things?

Comment: You never told us what $r_1, r_2,\ldots,r_m$ are. Is $r_i=\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}a_{ij}$ (with the assumption that all those series converge)?

Comment: Try using summations or elementary addition principles

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a given $m$, $s_{mn}-S$ is a sequence indexed by $n$. If $$-\epsilon< s_{mn}-S<\epsilon$$
then, as  $n\to \infty$, $s_{mn}\to (r_1+r_2+\dots +r_m)$, where $r_i=\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}a_{ij}$, and, by the Order Limit Theorem, the inequalities hold but they are no more strict:
$$-\epsilon\leq  (r_1+r_2+\dots +r_m)-S\leq\epsilon.$$

P.S. **Order Limit Theorem**: if $\exists N$ such that $a \leq b_n\, \forall n\geq N$, and $\lim_{n\to \infty} a_n=A$, $\lim_{n\to \infty} b_n=B$ then $A\leq B$.

Of course we can replace $a \leq b_n$ with the stronger assumption $a< b_n$ and we may conclude again that $A\leq B$.

Comment: @xxtensionxx Is it clear now?

Comment: Aah now I am with you! Thanks for a great answer!